# Only one of arguments should be allowed with CommandLineParser

Tags: c#, .net, command-line-parser

Im working on a console tool which accepts some arguments and then parses to the **Option** class.

What I need is a property that will verify if **only one of many marked fields in Option class** has values (arguments were delivered).

Ex.
Its ok when we run:

my.exe -a

my.exe -b

but NOT:

my.exe

my.exe -a -b

CommandLine.OptionAttribute cannot do such a thing. What i did is:
Main class args[] got extension .Parse:

```
args.Parse(options)` //where options is my Options class
```

inside:

```
CommandLine.Parser.Default.ParseArguments(args, options);
var isOnlyOneOfMany = options.GetType().GetProperties().Where(prop => Attribute.IsDefined(prop, typeof(OneOfMany)) && prop.GetValue(options) != null).Count() == 1;
```

how to do this better way?

Comment: `CommandLine` isn't a BCL class. Which library are you using?

Comment: What do you mean with "how to do this better way?" - what do you feel is wrong with your current approach?

Comment: CommandLine is a delivered library that I can use.

And Im just wondering if thats a good way to do such a thing and its not exaggeration.

Comment: *What* library? @ŁukaszMioduszewski

Comment: https://commandline.codeplex.com/

Comment: `var isOnlyOneOfMany = args.Length == 1;`

Comment: @ŁukaszMioduszewski could you post your `Options` class

Comment: http://pastebin.com/0n2ZEtyU

Comment: @ŁukaszMioduszewski which version you are using? since I cannot get the attribute `OneOfMany`

Comment: @ŁukaszMioduszewski your link points to an old site. CommandLineParser is hosted on Github now. The latest NuGet package version is 2.1.1-beta, released on November 2016

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will rewrite your `Options` class

```
class Options
{
    public int OneOfManyCount { get; private set;}

    // This is not OneOfMany
    [Option('n', "name", Required = true)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    private string _Value;
    [OneOfMany]
    [Option('v', "value", Required = true)]
    public string Value { get { return _Value; } set { _Value = value; OneOfManyCount++;} }

    private string _Date;
    [OneOfMany]
    [Option('d', "data", Required = true)]
    public string Data { get { return _Date; } set { _Date = value; OneOfManyCount++;} }
}
```

and in your `main`, you can call `options.OneOfManyCount` to get the number of arguments

```
    CommandLine.Parser.Default.ParseArguments(args, options);
    if(options.OneOfManyCount != 1) //Do something
```

And please notice if you have a `DefaultValue` attribute on one of you `OneOfMany`, it will hit the `set` one more time which means `OneOfManyCount` will have unexpected value.

Answer (score 0):

**Update: This solution doesn't work from version 2.8.0 because both SetName and Group are not allowed in option**

You can use `SetName` and `GroupName` to achieve this behavior:

`GroupName`: Available from version 2.7+

> An option group represents a group of options which are optional, but at least one should be available.

`SetName`: Available from version 1.9+

> It means that you can run commands of one set at a time. You can't mix
> commands of more than one set otherwise you get an error.

The new option class:

```
public class Options
{
    [Option('a', "aValue", Group = "Values", SetName = "ASet")]
    public bool AValue { get; set; }

    [Option('b', "aValue", Group = "Values", SetName = "BSet")]
    public bool BValue { get; set; }
}
```

How to parse the args:

```
var options = Parser.Default.ParseArguments<Options>(args);
```

Comment: When I try to combine Group and SetName, I get this error: "Both SetName and Group are not allowed in option"

Comment: As has been mentioned, you can't combine Group and SetName without getting the above error.  This makes no sense as it should be possible to have a group, which will require one of the options, and a SetName to restrict it to only one of the options.  For example, and add function and remove function.  You should be able to require one but not both to be specified.  The group would require one, and the SetName would restrict it to only one.

Comment: @UnionP I've updated the answer. As you mentioned, form version 2.8 is not possible to use `Group` and `SetName` in the same `Option`